# Can't install Eclipse With 1.8.0_221 and 64-bit java

Tags: java, eclipse

When I start the installer, it says

> Unfortunately the java version needed to run Eclipse installer couldn't be found on your system.
>   You need the following version or a higher version

But I did install the *8u221 kit (winx64)* of java.
And I install 64-bit JAVA while my computer is also 64-bit.
Also my java version is *1.8.0_221*

I found that methods in the Internet are all about 32-bit problem. But I did install 64-bit.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you checked whether the environment variable JAVA_HOME is set correctly? It needs to point to your SDK

Comment: You need the following version or a higher version, which version does it point to install

Comment: On a command prompt window, if you type "java -version" what does it print?

Comment: @RajendraGupta java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: @Javan I can successfully run it on command line.

Comment: Download and unzip a package from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ (to somewhere other than under "Program Files", and maybe don't rely on Windows Explorer to do the unzipping). You'll be able to add anything else to it afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem because I had installed java in the `Program Files(x86)` folder. I re-installed java in `C:\Program Files\Java` and then it was all ok.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse installer looks for JDK. Install JDK also. It worked for me.

Comment: Question clearly says "install the 8u221 kit (winx64) of java"

Answer (score 0):

If you  have the correct version of Java already installed and validated then run the Eclipse install as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

*You don't say what version of Eclipse you are using, so I will assume you are using a recent version.*

Since Eclipse 4.17 (2020-09) the required Java SE minimum version is 11, so you can't use Java SE 8.

You have 2 options:

- Use Eclipse 4.16 (2020-06) that requires Java SE 8;
- Or maybe, edit `eclipse.ini` and change line `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11` to `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8`. **Please note** that this can not work, or make Eclipse unstable.

Reference: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation